# How to start JMeter in GUI-mode?

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter

I'm new to unix, so maybe my problem is the one in front of the screen... I've a VM with Ubuntu Server 16.04 on it. To connect with it via rdp I installed xfce4 and xrdp. I can connect without problems.

Now I downloaded apache-jmeter-3.3.tgz (binary), unpack it and tried to start JMeter in GUI-mode -as described in the documentation- with doubleclicking on /.../jmeter/bin/jmeter. But only a Vim window pops of in which I can see the code of the file... I am not able to understand that problem. And it seems, that no one on the internet have had the same problem...

Any advices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On linux:

- Open a shell command
- go to jmeter/bin folder
- type:

  > ./jmeter

That's it provided you are not on a headless machine (without X)

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But I want to understand it... Why I can't start it with a simple doubleclick on the file? What would I have to do for that?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/465531/how-to-make-a-shell-file-execute-by-double-click

Comment: I can not upvote... not enough reputation... :( But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are trying to start JMeter GUI on a Linux server which has not GUI I have to inform you that this is not possible.
2. If your server runs with GUI then you may face issues starting the JMeter by simple double click on the icon. Try to open a console window navigate to your apache-jmeter.../bin folder and run the following command

   sudo bash jmeter.sh

Hope that I help